# Insert timestamp into filename when exporting into .csv

Tags: windows, file, powershell, timestamp, metadata

I am trying to insert the **timestamp into the filename** of an output file generated by PowerShell scrip.

So instead of `filelist.csv`, it names the output file with the actual timestamp (of the outpufile's modification time), like `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS_filelist.csv`.

```
Get-childitem -recurse -file | select-object @{n="Hash";e={get-filehash -algorithm MD5 -path $_.FullName | Select-object -expandproperty Hash}},lastwritetime,length,fullname | export-csv filelist.csv -notypeinformation
```

Any suggestions as to what is the missing code from the above line for timestamping the output file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
export-csv filelist.csv -notypeinformation
```

To:

```
Export-Csv "$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))_filelist.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Edit - `.ToString()` and `-UFormat`, generally**

When using `.ToString()` or `-Format`/`-UFormat`, you are passing a DateTime object and getting back a formatted string. In both cases you have to specify the format of the string you are after. The ways this format is specified differs.

Check out [this list of `.NET` format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) that can be used with `ToString()`/`-Format`. Note how e.g. `MM` is months 01-12, `M` is months 1-12 and `mm` is minutes 00-59.

[`-UFormat` is documented to use UNIX formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-5.1). I'm not familair with this at all, but the Notes section goes into detail. You can see here `%m` is month while `%M`

Comment: thank you! any advanateg of using `"$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss"))` vs.  `-Path "$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')`? normally, i am running this on different drives, machines, timezones, drives, etc.

Comment: @user3026965 More parenthesis?  You could even do `(Get-Date .. + 'filelist.csv')`

Comment: @user3026965 Advantage: not that I'm aware of. Imagine one will be (negligibly?) more optimal than the other. Difference: Yes, as they use different format strings - please see edit.

Answer (score 1):

In your file name, do as follows:

```
Export-Csv -Path "$(Get-Date -UFormat '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')_filelist.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: thank you (both seems to work, so i accepted the first answer.)

Comment: @user3026965 (This was the first answer)

Comment: i am confused then. i sort it "oldest", the other one comes on top. yet i see your "min ago".